# Best Way to Keep Up on Linux Log Files

Tags: monitoring, log-files, logrotate

I run multiple Linux (Ubuntu) web servers and am looking for a convenient way to keep tabs on important log files. I'd like to monitor pertinent LAMP logs as well as server accesses/logins.

Are there any convenient tools/utilities that will (a) rotate log files, (b) compress them, and (c) email or archive them for later viewing?

Comment: Not as an answer to your question, but you should look at centralizing your logs off-machine. Having all of your logs spooled into the same server assists with finding patterns which can act as precursors to critical errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) will do everything you list above and more e.g.

```
"/var/log/httpd/access.log" /var/log/httpd/error.log {
    compress
    rotate 5
    mail logs@your.address.example.com
    size 1M
    sharedscripts
    postrotate
        /usr/bin/killall -HUP httpd
    endscript
}
```

Would mail you the logs that are about to be deleted etc

Comment: Combine with logwatch and it will break out useful information in easily readable format too, plus its easy to extend.

Comment: Combine with Logstash and you get off-server centralised storage and indexing

Comment: logstash looks pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like Splunk? I collect 10gb of data per day with it..... :)

Comment: Its only free up to 500Mbyte per day though, above that it starts to be quite heavily priced. :/